# Scheduling a Quartz job

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I want to develop a quartz job which will run on a particular time specified within the job. But while I am starting the job it starts at that time not on that time which is specified within the code.

Please help.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.TimeZone;

import org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerFactory;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import org.quartz.TriggerBuilder;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

public class CronScheluderForActivityMilestone {

public boolean CronScheluderForActivityMilestone() throws Exception {

    SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    Scheduler sche = sf.getScheduler();
    sche.start();
    JobDetail jDetail = new JobDetail("SendMailOnActivityMileStone", "SendMailOnActivityMileStone", ActivityMileStoneSendMail.class);

    Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("mytriggerForActivityMileStone", "SendMailOnActivityMileStone")
            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.dailyAtHourAndMinute(19, 00).inTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta")))
            .forJob("SendMailOnActivityMileStone", "SendMailOnActivityMileStone")
            .build();

   sche.scheduleJob(jDetail, trigger);      
    return true;    
   }
  }
```

Comment: Can you try without setting inTimeZone? Additionally, since the JobDetail is an interface, can you replace with below?

JobDetail jDetail = newJob( ActivityMileStoneSendMail.class).withIdentity("SendMailOnActivityMileStone", "SendMailOnActivityMileStone").build();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your inTimeZone configuration like this :

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
.withSchedule(weeklyOnDayAndHourAndMinute(DateBuilder.WEDNESDAY, 10, 42)
.inTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles")))
.forJob(job)
.build();
```

**inTimeZone** belongs to withSchedule()